# My aunt made it to the airport 97 minutes before take-off and Emirates wouldn't check her in

Tags: emirates

Does she have any recourse? Is it because they overbooked? I was not present but it's an international flight and has been very disruptive and inconvenient to the family.

Comment: Far too many possibilities. As you said, maybe it was overbooked. Maybe her travel documents were not in order? Get the details from Emirates.

Comment: Travel documents were in order. She is definitely not a novice flyer. What are other reasons they would refuse her a seat? The gentleman was apparently quite rude and would only indicate that they should have made it to the airport sooner.

Comment: What airport was this at? Different airports have different rules on how early you have to be there for. What were the rules for the airport in question?

Comment: International or domestic flight? What does Emirates' rules state? Does the airport have rules?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what reason they told her why checking in was denied. It is hard to believe that none was given.

Comment: @frstrtd a gentleman is never rude :)

Comment: What did they say when she asked them?

Comment: @MarkMayo, do Emirates have any domestic flights?

Comment: http://www.emirates.com/us/english/plan_book/essential_information/dont_miss_your_flight.aspx says "Get to the check-in counter 90 minutes before your flight".  Was she?  It's unclear whether this would include being in line for the check-in counter.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy yes, Emirates Flight 5430 goes from Melbourne to Sydney, Australia, for example.

Comment: @MarkMayo That's a codeshare with Qantas, so not sure if it counts.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid dunno, but not everyone realises they're codesharing until they fly, plus it could be down to the airport's rules, was really my point about dom/intl flights. I think it comes down to really needing more info from the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Airlines have time limits at check in, if she was not checked in by the deadline, then she has no recourse.  It doesn't matter what time she arrived at the airport.  The only time that counts is when she presented herself to the counter agent to check in.

Comment: Absolutely and this I know and agree with. She was at the _counter_ speaking with the staff member with 7 minutes to spare. I shouldn't have written airport in the subject.